# Mysql: show everything that doesn't JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I messed my code a little and didn't delete posts on both tables and now I have 1000+ rows in `post_plus` that shouldn't be there.

How can I display all rows that doesn't JOIN?

for example, I've this query to join both tables

```
SELECT * FROM post JOIN post_plus ON post_plus.news_id = post.id
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM post JOIN post_plus ON post_plus.news_id = post.id WHERE post.id IS NULL

SELECT * FROM post JOIN post_plus ON post_plus.news_id = post.id WHERE post_plus.news_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select * from `post_plus` left join `post` on `post`.`id` = `post_plus`.`news_id` where `post`.`id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a left join

```
SELECT p.id, pp.id FROM post p LEFT JOIN post_plus pp ON (pp.news_id = p.id)
```

you will get all rows from post and pp.id will be null on those rows that don't match.

if you append a where clause you will get only the ones that do not match

```
SELECT p.id, pp.id FROM post p LEFT JOIN post_plus pp ON (pp.news_id = p.id) where pp.id is null
```

(tested)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'pp.id' in 'field list'

Comment: yep you have to use the right alias, edit the post, try again

Comment: Tested it, now try again. post was aliased "p" and post_plus "pp" in the ON clause you must use the right prefixes for the corresponding table or mysql can not find the columns. It should work as I tested it on my DB. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can also use this

```
select *
from   post      t1
join   post_plus t2
  on   t1.id <> t2.news_id
```

Comment: Which is just plain wrong. It would show too many results (a cross product actually with only a very small percent of rows removed.)

Comment: sorry,i made a mistake